# Efficient method to return first and last item from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement a more efficient method to return the first and last item of a `pandas` `df` where equal to a specific value. I'll post my current method below but there could be a more efficient way.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'X' :    ['X','Y','X','Z','X'],
    'Y' :    [2,5,3,5,1],
})

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So I want to return the first and last item in `Y` where `X == X`.

This is my attempt but I think there could be a more efficient way.

```
df = df[df['X'] == 'X']
df_first = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['X'], keep = 'first')
df_last = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['X'], keep = 'last')
df1 = pd.concat([df_first, df_last])

# my expected output
df1
   X  Y
0  X  2
4  X  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `query` (or any selection method, really) and `iloc`, this should be straightforward.

```
df.query('X == "X"').iloc[[0, -1]]

   X  Y
0  X  2
4  X  1
```

Assumes there are no NaNs in Y. Otherwise, chain `dropna`:

```
df.query('X == "X"').dropna(subset=['Y']).iloc[[0, -1]]

   X  Y
0  X  2
4  X  1
```

---

Another option using `agg`, thought this was interesting. **This is useful if your "Y" has NaNs.**

```
df.loc[df['Y'].where(df['X'] == 'X').agg(
    ['first_valid_index', 'last_valid_index'])]

   X  Y
0  X  2
4  X  1
```